# Coolant expansion tank issue

Tags: vw, cooling-system, golf, coolant-reservoir

My coolant tank is filled up to the correct level before driving off but I've taken a half an hour drive and it is very low and warning light comes on. Once stopped it cools down and the level rises. I've had it checked and theres no leak. Any ideas why it goes low very quickly and how I can sort this out?

Thanks
Anthony

Comment: By coolant expansion tank, do you mean something like what is pictured in [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/25605/12030) ?  This [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rZvTo.jpg) might also be helpful.

Comment: So is there really a leak if the level goes back to normal once the engine is cool?

Comment: What warning light is coming on?  Is it the temperature warning light or do you have a light for low coolant?

Comment: .....and, what year is the VW gold and what size engine?

Comment: JPHIL1618 yes looks a bit like it and garage has checked doesn't seem to have a leak.

Comment: Ducatikiller the red coolant light and it's a 2007 plate

Comment: This sounds like a very strange behavior! The only thing I can imagine would be that you have a rather large air pocket in your system, and as the water gets hot, it compress the air, and once it gets cold the air force the water back. It's a long shot, but you might want to make sure that the system is properly bleed.

Comment: Checked this morning and all the liquid had gone but garage I went to said it's not a leak but really weird.

Comment: might be the air pocket moved out and water got sucked in.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out?

Comment: try to prime the coolant circuit; on older engines that meant with the engine cold and off take out the reservoir cap, start and run the engine at idle until the cooling fan comes on, stop the engine, let it cool and put the cap back on.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an air pocket in the cooling system. Take the cap off of the overflow tank and radiator if possible and start the engine and turn the heat on so it'll circulate fully, allow the engine to reach operating temperature and the coolant level should drop as soon as its flushed the air pocket out, top off the system, replace caps and you're good to go.

Comment: If this doesn't work, consider draining and flushing the cooling system.  There is a bleed hole on a heater core hose used specifically to force air out when the cooling system is being refilled.  You will need to check the specific procedure for your model.